# Can not figure out how to modify fetch?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to add a authentication header, so far I have this but I am stuck here.

```
initialize: function(options) {
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, 'col'));

    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    window.dispatcher.trigger('queryBox:close');

    this.model.collectionName = this.col;

    if (this.model.id) {
        this.model.fetch();
    } else {
        this.renderNew();
        this.delegateEvents();
    }
},
```

Never used backbone before and I am clueless how I need to return the result so backbone can render it like the first one?

The result itself is correct, just need to pass it to backbone. In the first version it uses the default way to do it but can not figure it out how to do it manually.

```
fetch: function() {
    var self = this;

    Backbone.ajax({
            url: self.url(),
            headers: {'Authorization':jwt}
        })
        .done(function(res){
            console.log('Help')
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            tiedotApp.notify('danger', 'Error loading document: ' + jqXHR.responseText, 8000);
        })
},
```

Comment: Could you share the view which uses this model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not suggest you to change the default implementation of `fetch`, cause its behavior can be simply configured with **`options`** hash. But if you need to let's clarify few things.

**`model.fetch`** uses `jQuery.ajax()` for interactions with servers and all options passed to `fetch` will be passed to `$.ajax()` as well (a few of them can be rewritten in the middleware, but not for your case).

**`model.fetch`** needs to return promise to use it for done and fail callbacks chain.

---

You could implement your task in a few ways.

**1. If model fetched in one place:**

Then you can pass change it like:

```
model.fetch({
              headers:  {'Authorization':jwt}, 
              success: function () { consoele.log("Help") ;}, 
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
            });
```

**2. If model fetched in many places and you need to be DRY**

Rewrite fetch in this way:

```
fetch: function(options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.headers = options.headers || {};

    options.header['Authorization'}] = jwt;
    options.success = yourSuccessFunction;
    options.error = yourErrorFunction;   

    return this.constructor.__super__.fetch.call(this, options);
},
```

This way you will not break native implementation.